# Child Screen stays mounted after Parent is removed from screen. Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Below is the code that checks on app start whether to show the **AuthorizationScreen** or the **HomeScreen** (called **NavigationController** in my code).

When the state is Authentication**UnAuthenticated**, the **AuthorizaionScreen** is displayed.
The **AuthoriazationScreen** has 2 further screens for **SignUp** and **Login**.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      bloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context),
      builder: (context, state) {

        // * as long as the state is 'Authentication-Un-Initialized',
        // * the SplashScreen will remain visible
        if (state is! AuthenticationUninitialized) {
          FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
        }

        if (state is AuthenticationUnAuthenticated) {
          return AuthorizationScreen(userRepository: userRepository);
        }

        if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
          return const NavigationController();
        }

        if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
          return const LoadingScreen();
        }

        return const Center(
          child: Text('Auth State Error'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The **AuthorizationScreen** has a button that pushes LoginScreen to stack.
**CustomPageRoute** is to add transition from left to right.

```
PrimaryButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      CustomPageRoute(
        child: BlocProvider.value(
          value: _loginBloc,
          child: const SignInScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: const Text('Sign In'),
)
```

*The Problem:*

From the **AuthorizationScreen** when i open the LoginScreen and enter details and login the user. The **state** changes to Authentication**Authenticated**, and the **NavigationController** is mounted.

**But still the LoginScreen is the visible screen. Only when i press the back button the LoginScreen pops and the NavigationController becomes visible.**

Shouldn't the **LoginScreen** be removed when the state was changed and the **NavigationController** should be the visible screen.

Comment: What you are looking for is `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(...)`

Comment: You cannot mount screens like normal widgets, you have to add them to your navigation stack as mentioned by @davidn, you are doing it right in AuthorizationScreen, do the same in your BlocBuilder, instead of just returning it